# Irreducibility over field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to show that $p(x)=x^2-1-\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

What I tried: Assume by contradiction that $p(x)$ is reducible; then it has a root $r$. We know that $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a degree 3 extension over $\mathbb{Q}$), so $r = a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $p(r) = a^2+4bc-1+2(ab+c^2-1/2)\sqrt[3]{2} + (2ac+b^2)\sqrt[3]{4}=0$. Since the basis is independent, we have the following system of equations:

- $a^2+4bc-1=0$
- $2(ab+c^2)-1=0$
- $2ac+b^2=0$

However I cannot see how this system of equations brings a contradiction to the reducibility assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Show the root of $p(x)$ satisfies $(x^2-1)^3=2$. Deduce it is a root of $q(x)=x^6-3x^4+3x^2-3$. Apply Eisenstein to show that $q(x)$ is irreducible. Deduce that a root of $q(x)$ cannot be contained in an extension of degree 3 of $Q$.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a hint for the last step ?